# RESTful: How to perform different actions on the same url?

Tags: rest

As far as I know, according to RESTful guidelines, every url should represent a single resource or a group of resources, and actions should be put as arguments.

Assume we have a group of resources named 'users', and I want to register one more user,
so the api could be:

```
POST /users HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com

username=<username>&password=<password>&email=<email>&age=<age>
```

Now if I want to unregister a user, then of the unregister api:

Method will still be `POST`,
URI will still be `/users`,
arguments may be   `username=<username>&password=<password>&reason=<reason>`

In this situation, two apis share the same url and method with different arguments, and I think it's not a good design.

So question is:
What is the good design against this situation, to make the server-end easier to distinguish two different actions on the same resource?

**EDIT**
I really appreciate @Tim's suggestions and now I want my question to be more generic:
If there are several different updating actions on a resource, and each of the actions takes different combination of arguments, how should I work out RESTful apis now? Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you register a user by making a POST (create) request, the opposite - unregistering - should be a DELETE request.

**Registering**

```
POST /users HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com

username=<username>&password=<password>&email=<email>&age=<age>
```

**Unregistering**
You can choose to make a request to `/users` with the username and password (for verification) in the request body

```
DELETE /users HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com

username=<username>&password=<password>&reason=<reason>
```

Or make a request to `/users/<username>` with the password (for verification) and a reason (for whatever purpose) in the request body

```
DELETE /users/<username> HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com

&password=<password>&reason=<reason>
```

I think the latter is better.

Comment: How to work it out depends on what you use for backend, but i think that is an entirely different issue that deserves its own question :-)

Comment: 'what you use for backend', can you explain more? Sorry I'm not quite clear about what you mean.

Comment: When you said `how should I work out RESTful apis now?` i thought you were asking help setting up your server/backend

Comment: I've proposed a new [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26447254/restful-apis-when-multiple-actions-on-the-same-uri), please check it out. :)